# Are there any c++ metaprogramming alternatives besides templates?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have been using metaprogramming quite a lot, but sometimes the combination of c macros and templates are just not enough.

I suppose the drawback would potentially be lack of cross-platform compatibility if the metaprogramming platform is only for, say, linux etc.

So yeah, is there such thing available right now, besides templates? Google search for metaprogramming is dominated by template metaprogramming, so it's hard to find right now..

**edit**: here's an example on something I've been working on.

Suppose I have a generic class for saving/loading files into and from buffers. Let's call it FilePack.

I have a define macro, which looks like

```
  defineFilePack(BaseClass, "code-a")
```

It basically creates a class called "BaseClassPack", which is defined to be a subclass. Below is that thing.

```
class FilePack{
   public:
      char * thebuffer;
      int bufsize;
      string packcode;

      // and constructors etc
      FilePack(const string& thecode, int bufsize);
      void operator=(FilePack& rhs);
      void saveToFile(const string& filename);
      void loadFromFile(const string& filename);
      // .. and all the function you'd expect to see in a class like this

};

// the person details

class PersonDetails{
   public:
      solidstring<64> name;
      int age;
      DateTime birthday;
      // .. yada yada yada
};


defineFilePack(PersonDetails, "psd")

// the above creates the following class

class PersonDetailsPack : public FilePack{
   public:
      PersonDetailsPack():
         FilePack("psd", sizeof(PersonDetails)){ // etc

      }

      PersonDetails& get(){
         return *(PersonDetails*)getBuffer();
      }

      // and a lot more convenience function

};
```

Now, there's actually an in-built check by FilePack's constructor that the declared code matches with the size, using a global map.

Right now I'm stumped on how to do that using template metaprogramming, which is actually a good fit for it because all of these filepack codes are declared inside the source file. Sure, someone can probably make their own FilePack in run-time, but that's besides the point.

Another thing that metaprogramming could help with here is to support loading different versions of FilePack. Suppose I had to update the PersonDetails class.. I just make a new class, use some kind of metaprogramming to declare the inheritance, and magically make FilePack know so that when it's loading an old version of PersonDetails it can call the conversion function, or whatever.

Also, you're welcome to comment on that architecture, and I'm keen to hear any comments about it, but it might be a bit off-topic?

Comment: Can you provide an example of something where templates + macros are not enough? This would be a good start point for the discussion.

Comment: @David Rodriguez: For example generating code that serializes classes over a network connection or that in general does something for every member.

Comment: "but sometimes the combination of c macros and templates are just not enough" -- what is missing/not enough?

Comment: Templates & Macros are not enough?! :D My mind suffers when digging in one of them, imagine mixing both!

Comment: @6502 - I've done it.  I know it's enough.

Comment: @Noah: Amazing... last time I wasted time on that was impossible to get real introspection on data members. Probably something changed or you didn't understand what I meant (long ago i read a proposal from stroustrup for compile time introspection but I didn't know actually got anywhere). But still IMO extreme template metaprogramming techniques are much overrated and to my eyes are just a funny "i can do it" exercise like handwalking. Impressive, but quite a stupid way to move around unless you're in a circus.

Comment: @Noah: Sure, it might be possible, but I was wondering if there's less painful ways to do things. I wish the C macro is a bit smarter than it is right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also metaprogram with the preprocessor.

You could consider using special purpose preprocessors to generate code as "metaprogramming" as well.  Then you could include things like lex/yacc and the Qt MOC.

Comment: That MOC thing is what I was looking for, too bad it's QT :/ but in concept it seems to be the most practical thing right now..

That probably counts as a language on top of a language I guess?

Comment: I don't see why its "too bad it's Qt". I find Qt to be excellent at what it is made for and more! </bias>

Answer (score 2):

Inside the language, you can only use templates or macros to metaprogram. The metaprogramming facilities offered by, say, the Boost Preprocessor library, which implements some truly amazing things as macros, are exceedingly powerful.

However, if you want to get a little bit more out there, you could use a scripting language of your choice to metaprogram.

Comment: I've always wondered how boost does their things. I've never really used them, but it seems like there's a lot of arcane stuff inside them.

Answer (score 2):

If you define metaprogramming as writing code that generates code, then you have

- Templates.
- The preprocessor.
- Other preprocessing (usually scripts, but sometimes compiler extension)
- Generating C++ source from C++ code, compile on the fly, load as shared lib.
- Possibly, but that's stretching it, also generating machine code, like trampoline stubs.

I think the most interesting that isn't template or C++ preprocessor, is language extensions that support cross concern programming, [**aspect-oriented programming**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), like, logging method calls or serializing.

As I recall ParcPlace made a tool for that?

Hm, that reminds me to not forget to check it out, sometime. :-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: See my answer on program transformation systems, which generalize aspect-oriented programming.  Aspects provide only very limited ways to modify your code, and that sense they are like templates, which also provide a limited (but different) way.  Program transformations systems can carry out arbitrary modifiications; you are limited by your ambitions and ability to express what you want to do, rather than by what the specific metaprogramming technique can do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this job is perfect for example for Python. The easy way is to use a custom file format for describing how the classes are made and then you can generate both implementation and interface (even in multiple languages).

Parsing existing C++ header files is instead sort of a nightmare because of the complex C++ syntax... (and why limiting yourself in what you want to express ?).

Python is multiplatform and a very nice language per se...

As an example the following is an example of "augmented" C++ I used...

```
//
// U8 -> F32 format converter
//
//    - src(Image:U8) ............ source image
//    - dst(pImage:F32:src) ...... destination image
//
ImgFilter u8_to_f32(Image& src, Image& dst)
{
    const double k = 1.0/255;
    for (int y=0; y<src.h; y++)
    {
        unsigned char *rp = src.u8(0, y);
        float *wp = dst.f32(0, y);
        for (int x=0,w=src.w; x<w; x++)
            *wp++ = *rp++ * k;
    }
}
```

The comment above the function and the name/parameters are read by a python script that generates the .h for the function, C++ code that handles memory allocation, size and format compatibility checks, command line argument parsing, online help and a python binding.
Basically I can write only the "meat" and having all the boilerplate generated for me. The python script doing this is 200 lines and given the amount of generated code the C++ boilerplate for just a couple of filters is already more than that.

Comment: Long ago I decided to ignore the C++templatesarethebestthingintheworld mafia with which it's impossibile to do any logical reasoning in what is good to do with templates (many things) and what is not (many other things). It's ages that my first concern is not fighting between compilers incompatibilities in dark areas of the C++ syntax and I really don't miss those times.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because the guy read "this job is perfect for python", immediately reading you as a troll or something.

I like that approach, but it actually seems like a lot of work. That's like making a language on top of c++ that still works with existing stuff.. that would be awesome.

Comment: FYI, +1 doesn't counter a -1, it counters 5 of them.

Comment: @kamziro: it's less that one would suspect, but of course a lot depends on what you need to do with it. I added an example where I decided to just add formatted comments and a special typedef to a regular C++ source file to add the information the code generator needed.

Comment: @Noah: Probably Alf is not reputation obsessed (and IIRC also not template-obsessed either) and he was thinking to the article, not to my reputation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform arbitrary manipulation of code, you want a general purpose metaprogramming tools such as a program transformation system.   These tools accept source code, and carry out arbitrary analyses/modifications to that code according to your needs, using compiler-like technology.

Our  [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSTookit.html) is exactly such a system.  It is parameterized by an explicit description of the programming language to be processed, and by the task you want it to carry out on your source code.   DMS is unique in being generic like this (Jackpot is a Java-only program transformation system), and doubly-unique in having a robust [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) which has been used for large-scale transformation tasks on production C++ system.

With a front end, DMS can parse the source code to abstract syntax trees, build symbol tables, execute pattern matches or code transformations using patterns written directly in C++ terms, and regenerate compilable source code with comments and the original formats of literals (complete with number radix, etc.).  Your program modification can be any computation you can define over ASTs.  In short, it can do, from outside the language, what language-supported metaprogramming features cannot do.